# CASE GETDATE() - GETDATE() in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

can anyone explain the below example?

Query

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (GETDATE() - GETDATE()) < 31 THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) [Result],
(CASE WHEN (GETDATE() - '2020-08-30') < 31 THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) [Result1],
(CASE WHEN (GETDATE() - '2020-07-30') < 31 THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) [Result2],
(CASE WHEN (GETDATE() - '2020-07-30') < 31 THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) [Result3]
```

Output

```
Result  Result1 Result2 Result3
1        1      0       0
```

I want to know just way `Result` and `Result1` has `1` and else `0`?

Actual Query

```
SELECT  ((CASE WHEN (GETDate()-[InvBillDate])<31 then 1 
else 
(case when (GETDate()-[InvBillDate])<61 And (GETDate()-[InvBillDate])>30 then 2 
else 
(case when (GETDate()-[InvBillDate])<91 And (GETDate()-[InvBillDate])>60 then 3 
else 4 end) 
end) end)) AS [ColNo] 
FROM [dbo].[Invoice] (NOLOCK)
```

Comment: Subtraction of dates is going to return a number measured in days.

Comment: Hi, @shawnt00 thanks for the comment can you please share any example if it's possible?

Comment: `getdate() - getdate()` is always zero. `9/9` - `8/31` is 9. 9 is less than 31. I'm not sure what kind of example you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind, I suggest this way to shorten a bit the query.

```
SELECT (
       (CASE WHEN (GETDate()-[InvBillDate])<31 then 1 
       else 
       (case when (GETDate()-[InvBillDate])<61 then 2 
       else 
       (case when (GETDate()-[InvBillDate])<91 then 3 
       else 4 
       end) end) end)
       ) AS [ColNo] 
FROM [dbo].[Invoice] (NOLOCK)
```

Answer (score 0):

With limited context, I will try to interpret the query.

It is trying to calculate the date difference between today and the billing date, then based on that categorize the date differences into 4 groups:

- Within 31 days
- 31 - 60 days
- 61 - 90 days
- More than 90 days